# The Oracle SQL Developer has been loading for more than 1 hours when it is set up

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to install Oracle and Oracle SQL Developer to learn at school. I follow [this guide on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUpvXMHqe2U) but my Oracle SQL Developer has been loading like this for more than 1 hour (nearly 10%) and doesn't load more until now. I've searched the Internet and I tried some methods to fix this issue but it doesn't make sense.

[image]

Do you guys have any ideas about it? How can I fix this problem?
Please help me, I really need it to learn at school.

Thank you so much. My Oracle SQL Developer version is the latest version (23.1.0). Its location is in drive C: - the same drive as the Oracle19c.

Comment: Close the application. Open the command prompt, change directory to wherever you installed SQL developer and then run the executable from the command prompt. Look at what gets output to console while it is loading and then do what you need to do to fix the errors. You have not provided any way for people to understand what issue has occurred that is making it run for a long time) so it is unlikely that you will get a solution unless you can provide more details.